# I can't seem to get the "before skip" command to correctly execute

Tags: tcolorbox

I am trying to create a title page for my thesis that involves a floating box with a title, university logo, author etc. in it. I have set up the box environment as I would like it, but I cannot position it at the bottom of the page! I have posted an MWE below. The 10cm is just a placeholder value. What I would really like is to have the box aligned to the bottom of my title page.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[before skip=10cm,]

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `before skip` sets the amount of glue. If there's no text before the box, there's nothing to skip

Answer (score 4):

The `before skip` option is only useful if there is something *before* that should be skipped.

A 'better' way is to insert explicit vertical space and use `float=b` in order to let the `tcolorbox` box float to the bottom, followed by `\clearpage`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[code={\vphantom{This floats away}\thispagestyle{empty}},float=b]
How not to be seen
\end{tcolorbox}

\clearpage% Ship out here

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it as an MWE and it worked perfectly. However when I tried it in my thesis document, it floated to the middle of the page after the title page?

Comment: @louden255: Well, your example did not show the title page, did it? If you're using a different setup for the title page, another solution is necessary for **another** question! A title page is not necessarily done with `\maketitle` or `\begin{titlepage}...\end{titlepage}`

Comment: Sorry, this is my first LaTex document, and I still am struggling to work out which things interact with one another, I shall post another question. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @louden255: The correct way to thank users is to accept their answer ;-)